# How to get Gmail notified when a label has new unread message?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, notifications

I create a label for facebook/twitter incoming notification messages and auto archive them into associative labels using filter.

That way, I don't get notified when new messages arrived. So what I need is to get notified in some other way (popup or send an one email per hour saying that I have new mail in that label).

How can I get that?

**Update**

- The number of notification mails is huge; which makes my inbox flooded with notification

Comment: Are you using Android? If just desktop, which browser?

Comment: @AlEverett I'm using desktop; browser to be Firefox or Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Checker Plus for Gmail [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj)

Looking for the similar one for Firefox but not found yet.

Google search

[image]

Installed it and go to option

[image]

Config for the labels

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[GmailAssistant](http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/) is a Java application that purports to monitor multiple accounts and labels.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want a desktop-based application though.

Answer (score 1):

[Gmail Notifier](http://email.about.com/od/gmailmailcheckers/gr/gmail_firefox.htm?rd=1) is a Firefox extension that puts new icons in your toolbar or status bar. It doesn't appear to let you jump right to the message(s) however; it's purely for notification.

Comment: Any suggestion for Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "gmail label notifier chrome" or at least looking in the Chrome store? We're not your personalized search service.

Comment: I did have a search indeed but there were so plenty of them that I need your help. Sorry I didn't mean to treat you as a  search service.

Comment: It's pretty academic to click "Add to Chrome" for one of the extensions, try it out, and remove it if you don't like it. The Stack Exchange sites are not good for recommendation engines.

Comment: At last, I did try. Thank you very much for your help. `Checker Plus for Gmail` is the one. I love to pick your answer to  be an accepted one with more detail.

Comment: I tried with firefox 12.0 but this exetnsion is not available though.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way. Have the filter add the label, but don't have them auto archived. They will end up in the inbox.

When you have read them, just click archive. The archive command reoves the Inbox label, but keeps the other labels in place.

Comment: This is not what I need since number of notification mails is huge

Comment: @NamGVU If the volume is high for that label, it seems like there would almost always be something new. If that's the case, you'd get your new notification popup/email every hour (or whatever) almost without question. That does not tell you anything interesting except which hour-long block you should look at that label (not much benefit). Maybe you could just check the label every hour? Any unread messages you find there would be since your last check. Select all and mark as read. Return to your other work.

Answer (score 1):

GMail should show you the label in the left pane by default once there's an unread message. This means your filter must be set only to auto-archive matching messages; it must not mark them as read.

If the label isn't showing up in the pane despite having new unread messages in it, you need to change its settings. Go to [Label Settings page](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/labels), scroll down to your label, and click `show if unread` if it's blue. There's no "Save" button for this section so you can return to your inbox or whatever else you need to do.

[image]

Comment: I need to have notification - not the number of unread. Reason: I have many unread notification mails which I would never read indeed; i.e. the unread number is increased and I need to know each time it does

Answer (score 1):

Are you comfortable writing code? If you are, have a look at context.io/docs/2.0/accounts/webhooks. Use the filter_folder_added option to set your label and the sync_period to set the interval to look for new messages. This will make a POST request to any URL when there's a new message in that label and you can code the rest.

Comment: I do like coding but looking for some already-made tool first. Thanks anyway.